# tight savefig without axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, savefig

When using a matplotlib to draw something without axes, `savefig()` isn't truly "tight":

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circ = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1.0)
plt.gca().add_artist(circ)
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.axis("off")
# plt.show()
plt.savefig("out.svg", bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image]

That's because the SVG contains the hidden "background patch"

```xml
  <g id="patch_1">
   <path d="M 0 280.512 
L 280.512 280.512 
L 280.512 0 
L 0 0 
z
" style="fill:none;"/>
  </g>
```

How to remove it?

Comment: Could you try `plt.savefig("out.svg", bbox_inches="tight", transparent=True)`?

Comment: @Sheldore Doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe also set `plt.gcf().patch.set_visible(False)` before saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pad_inches` option!

```py
plt.savefig("out.svg", bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0)
```